# Is Bucket Sort stable when using Quick Sort in Bucket Sort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Recently, I am learning sorting algorithm. When learning Bucket Sort, I have the question  of title. I know Quick Sort is unstable, and wiki says Bucket Sort is stable at [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Stable_sorts). But is it still stable when using Quick Sort in Bucket Sort? I can't imagine what will happen, can anyone help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Short answer is no.

Comment: So the reason is because Quick Sort is unstable, right?@MBo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any unstable sort may change item order in a bucket. When you merge buckets, this violated order remains.

Imagine we have buckets `0..9` with point `(5,5)` and bucket `20..29` contains points `(22,3), (21,14), (22,7)`. After unstable sort (by the first key)  we can see order like `(21,14), (22,7), (22,3)` (just example). After merging we can see

```
 (5,5), (21,14), (22,7), (22,3)
```

where mutual order of points with `x=22` has been changed

If we use, for example, insertion sort inside buckets, we have guarantee that result is

```
 (5,5), (21,14), (22,3), (22,7)
```